# Add "rgb" legend to R leaflet heatmap

Tags: r, leaflet, data-visualization, heatmap

I made some interactive heatmaps using **leaflet** (particularly the **addHeatmap()** command from the **leaflet.extras** package) and **shiny**. Having created a desired map, I would like to add a legend to it.

What I am interested in is a "rgb" legend, based on density values deduced by **addHeatmap()** from pure long/lat coords. 
What I need is something like this map - https://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/example-legend-tooltip.html - unfortunately I have no knowledge of JS and can't rewrite this code in terms of R/include the right fragment of JS code for my problem.

What I tried so far is the **addLegend()** command, which does not give the desired result, as in this case I would need to specify a variable for which the legend would be prepared. I also tried to extract the color range and assigned values from created leaflet object, however with no success.

Here's link to full data to run the reproducible example on:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h3jL_PU6DGTtdIWBK02Tt37R7IB2ArH9/view

And here's top 20 records:

```
structure(list(latitude = c(30.309522, 30.24429616, 30.30038194, 
                            30.27752338, 30.23294081, 30.23038507, 
                            30.34285933, 30.24962237, 30.26594744, 
                            30.20515821, 30.22363485, 30.2759184, 
                            30.28283226, 30.33816909, 30.26611565, 
                            30.18835401, 30.26704789, 30.27456699, 
                            30.19237135, 30.1925213), 
              longitude = c(-97.73171047, -97.77446858, -97.77885789, 
                            -97.71919076, -97.58937812, -97.76581095, 
                            -97.73598704, -97.72215443, -97.74144275, 
                            -97.8782895, -97.78329845, -97.71321066, 
                            -97.70820152, -97.82413058, -97.7327258, 
                            -97.81606795, -97.68989589, -97.7580592, 
                            -97.7816127, -97.73138523)), 
                .Names =  c("latitude", "longitude"), row.names = 
                                c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here's an example code, which I'd like to extend by the mentioned functionality:

```
library(magrittr)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)

data <- read.csv('DATA.csv')
leaflet(data) %>%
  addTiles(group="OSM") %>%
  addHeatmap(group="heat", lng = ~longitude, lat = ~latitude, max=.5, blur = 60)
```

And here is the result of that code (on whole dataset):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VFNC.jpg

**So to sum up what I would like to do**: based on such picture I would like to extract the range of the drawn colors along with values assigned to them, and draw legend using that information.

Is there something I am missing? It looks like a pretty simple issue, but I've been struggling to find a solution for past few hours. 
Thanks in advance for any help!

**EDIT**: extended the reproducible example.

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/legends.html

Comment: Hard to troubleshoot if you don't provide a reproducible example...

Comment: Thank You, but I've already seen that link, and made some attempts using addLegend(). As I stated (maybe not clearly enough), I do not want to create the legend based on any additional variable present in the dataset. Instead I wish to rely only on density of (x,y) points, resulting from the algorithm used by addHeatmap(). The code above is my minimal reproducible example, missing the functionality I am interested in.

Comment: Can you post the output of `dput(data)` (or `dput(head(data,20))` if your data set is big)? That makes your example reproducible because without your data it's hard to troubleshoot your specific issue.

Comment: I already posted the data as a google drive link earlier, but now I've also added the `dput(head(data,20))` for more convenience.

Comment: I'm struggling with the exact same issue... @Crimmlaz: Have you found a solution back then? Or anybody know how to solve it?

Comment: @LisardoErman Unfortunately I had no luck finding the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample data does not have any values to it to actually map a density overlay.

You can specify the number of bins with `colorBin()` and then specify those bins with your `pal` function. You can set the bins differently depending on your needs at the `data_values` distributions. The help section of `colorBin()` is helpful in identifying the correct parameters for your needs.

```
bins <- c(0,1,2,3,4)
pal <- colorBin("Spectral", domain = data_value, bins = bins, na.color = "transparent")

m <-leaflet() %>% 
      addTiles() %>% 
      addHeatmap(lng= long_cords, lat = lat_cords, intensity = data_value,
                 blur = 20, max = 400, radius = 15, cellSize = 3) %>%     
      addLegend(pal = pal, values = data_value,
                title="Heat map legend")
```

You'll have to play around with the `addHeatmap` arguments to get an the right transparency and density settings.