# Add legend to leaflet heatmap

Tags: javascript, leaflet, heatmap

I'm trying to add a legend to my leaflet heatmap, [like this tutorial shows](https://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/example-legend-tooltip.html), but I haven't been able to do it, also I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48011859/add-rgb-legend-to-r-leaflet-heatmap) post but no answers were given [update: there is one now]. This is my code. Any help will be appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    Heatmap with Leaflet
  </title>
  <!-- link to leaflet css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
  <!-- map is full width and height of device -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <style>
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    html,
    body,
    #map {
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- leaflet js -->
  <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.js">
  </script>
  <script src="leaflet-heat.js"></script>
  <script>
    var heat_points = [
      [0.8299, -71.0696],
      [0.8325, -70.9852],
      [4.6912, -69.4049],
      [4.6904, -69.4241],
      [4.6844, -69.4296],
      [7.9843, -75.8012],
      [5.93, -76.0737],
      [5.9317, -76.0719],
      [5.894, -76.0492],
      [5.9322, -76.0726],
      [5.9318, -76.0721],
      [5.9333, -76.0767],
      [5.9328, -76.0761],
      [5.945, -76.0767],
      [5.944, -76.0751],
      [0.9261, -71.7717],
      [7.265, -76.5464],
      [-2.2926, -72.9175],
      [-2.2547, -73.024],
      [0.6353, -71.7998],
      [0.615, -71.7906],
      [8.5221, -81.3771]
    ]
  </script>
  <div id="map">

  </div>
  <script>
    var map = L.map('map', {
      center: [4.0615, -73.5645],
      zoom: 5
    });

    // OSM Baselayer
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);

    var heatmap = L.heatLayer(heat_points, {
      radius: 12,
      blur: 25,
      maxZoom: 11
    }).addTo(map);
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```